# добавление 3d сцены в форму visual studio

Tags: c#, form, 3d

Всем привет, возникла задача добавить 3d сцену в окно формы в Visual studio, подскажите каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: что значит 3d сцену?...что на ней должно быть ?

Comment: допустим на форме есть panel в нее добавляем fbx файл из 3d max с анимацией, необходимо управлять этой анимацией из кода, как то так